# control not entering in fold() method

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

i am trying to insert data from form to database but on form submission control does not enter in fold(error, success) method and runs the statement after it and redirects it to other page

this is my controller method

```
def submitinfo = Action { implicit request => 
      signupForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
          errors => BadRequest(views.html.signup(errors)),
          data => {
            println("************enter sucess case *********************")
            signupcc.insertData(data.name, data.username, data.email, data.password)
          })
      println("************Redirecting to sucess page *********************")
      Redirect(routes.Application.success)
  }
```

here is my routes file

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /signup                     controllers.Application.signup
POST    /submit                     controllers.Application.submitinfo
GET     /success                    controllers.Application.success
GET     /signin                     controllers.Application.signin
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: Don't think of it as "not entering the fold" method, but instead it's entering the error branch, then discarding the result because the final `Redirect` in your code is what the function will always return.

Comment: yes you are right @m-z but it does not show any error on console then how can i know what the error is ?

Comment: Are you displaying the error? I.e. do you have in your signup.scala.html something like `@if(signupForm.hasErrors) { ... @signupForm.errors.map { error => ...`?

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` action should be part of **sucess case** inside `fold` method:

```
def submitinfo = Action { implicit request => 
  signupForm.bindFromRequest().fold(errors => BadRequest(views.html.signup(errors)),
      data => {
        println("************enter sucess case *********************")
        signupcc.insertData(data.name, data.username, data.email, data.password)
        println("************Redirecting to sucess page *********************")
        Redirect(routes.Application.success)
      })
}
```

Comment: i have tried it but now it does not redirect it to next page

Comment: tell us what does happen. your fold is like "if errors, reload signup form, else { do insertData and reload success page.} So what does happen after a success?

Comment: in success case it calls the insertData method to insert the data in database and then it redirects to next page showing **signup successful**  message